# Fetch Lookup data from Table to another table in Access Webapp

Tags: ms-access-2010, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013, sharepoint-apps, ms-access-web-app

my question here is related to **Access Webapp**.

There are 2 Tables: 
1. User Entry- Primary Data.
2. User Entry- Planning Data.

In **User Entry- Primary Data** i have Fields with its Data types
1.SAP ID
2.Project Name
3.Project Manager
4.Group Head
5.Gross Margin
6.Advances
7.Retention
8.T&D For Stock Items
9.T&D for Trading Items

In **User Entry- Planning Data** i have same fields with data types as **Lookup**
1.SAP ID
2.Project Name
3.Project Manager
4.Group Head
5.Gross Margin
6.Advances
7.Retention
8.T&D For Stock Items
9.T&D for Trading Items

and more values...

What i want is once i enter data in **User Entry- Primary Data** I want the same Values in in **User Entry- Planning Data**.

as in the below image #4 only SAP ID is fetched,  but all the other fields are blank. How do i auto fetch those specific data's?

[User Entry- Primary Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcnXa.png)

[User Entry- Planning Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqK2C.png)

Note: 2 more images are in Comments section Namely 3 & 4

Thank you!

Regards 
Satish

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rs429.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wzrz.png

Comment: How do you auto fetch the ID

Comment: what do u mean? be specific @dbmitch

Comment: do u mean how did I auto fetch the SAP ID? If that was your question, I hope you see 3rd image or image no [3] , in that there is a column called Add User Entry- Planning Data: SAP ID, so it did auto fetch the data from SAP ID Only, not from other fields. that way I got the SAP ID auto fetched. how do I do the same for all the rest 8 columns from Project Name till T&D for Trading Items.

Comment: why is this tagged as `Access 2010` and `Access 2013`

Comment: because it is being developed in Access Webapp (linked to SharePoint) @dbmitch